# Symlink to raspberry pi webroot breaks

Tags: web, raspberry-pi, symlink

I have my raspberry pi setup as an internal web server. I have an external hard drive connected to the pi and mounted correctly.

I then symlink two folders from the hard drive to the web root on the pi, one is /Movies, and the other is /Series.

Initially this all works fine, as in if I hit http://192.168.1.17/Movies I get a list of all the files, I then click one and it starts playing no problem. However, after leaving it for a while and coming back, I can still get to the file directory in /Movies or /Series, but when I click a file, the web browser cannot open it.

I have no idea what's going on, it seems weird that I can still access the file directory, but playing a file doesn't work?

Any thoughts or help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an apache server?

If so Symlinking is not a good idea.

An alternative which is more secure and may fix your problem is to install Userdir

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

Then you need to make a directory in home

```
mkdir public_html
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you want to change the home directory apache points to you can do so in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf .Then change the `<Directory /home/*/public_html>` to the directory you want.

To access you're server simply enter ip_of_Rpi/~pi_username. e.g 192.168.0.100/~pi

more details here: http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2012/10/how-to-enable-and-configure-apache2-userdir-module-in-ubuntu-server-12-04.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache web server, you can use *mod_alias* to map some directory in a URL path like this

```
Alias /mnt/external_disk01/movies /Movies
Alias /mnt/external_disk02/series /Series
```

Before use alias, make sure it is activated.
To activate:

```
a2enmod alias
```

more info in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html